# HTML server sent events crashing Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

I have been working on developing a Social Networking application based on LAMP. But visiting it sometimes takes me to the Google Chrome "Aw Snap! Something Went wrong" page. However, it works fine on all other browsers. It's due to Running two SSE(server sent events) in the background simultaneously.

Moreover, I tried removing the Server Sent Events, and it seems to solve the problem as I didn't get to see the error then. Also, the website became a bit faster. But I need them as a major feature on my page. What can be done to make it work?

The scripts for the same are:

chat.php

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{ 
  var source2=new EventSource("onlineStudents.php");
  source2.onmessage=function(event2)
  {
     var data=JSON.parse(event2.data);
     $("#chat_head_number").html(": "+data['total']);
     for(var i=1;i<30;i++)
     {
        $("#chat_states_number"+i).html(" ");
        x=$("#state"+i).text();
        for( var j=0;j<data['statesName'].length;j++)
        {
             if(data['statesName'][j]==x)
             {
                 $("#chat_states_number"+i).html(" : "+data['statesNumber'][j]);
              }
        }
     }
   }
 }
 </script>
```

onlineStudents.php

```
<?php session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
$query="Select * from online_students where email<>'$_SESSION[user]'";
$result=  queryMysql($query);
$data["total"]=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query="Select distinct state from online_students";
$result=queryMysql($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $query2="select * from online_students where state='$row[state]' and email<>'$_SESSION[user]'";
    $result2=queryMysql($query2);
    $data["statesName"][]=$row['state'];
    $data["statesNumber"][]=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
$query="Select distinct college from online_students";
$result=  queryMysql($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $query2="Select * from online_students where college='$row[college]' and email<>'$_SESSION[user]'";
    $result2=queryMysql($query2);
    $data["collegesName"][]=$row['college'];
    $data["collegesNumber"][]=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
echo "data:".json_encode($data)."\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(3);
?>
```

header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{
  var source=new EventSource("checkMessages.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
  {
      $("#new_message").html("Inbox"+event.data);
  };
}
else
{
  $("#new_message").html("HTML5 not supported");
} 
</script>
```

checkMessages.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$userid=studentidOf($_SESSION['user']);
$query="Select distinct msgby from messages where msgfor='$userid'";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k=mysql_num_rows($result);

$query="Select postnumber from notifications where notifor=$userid and postnumber is NOT NULL";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
$collegeid=collegeidOf($_SESSION['user']);
$query="Select collegeid_post from notifications where notifor=$userid and      collegeid_post=$collegeid and notiby<>$userid";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query="Select collegeid_forum from notifications where notifor=$userid and collegeid_forum=$collegeid and notiby<>$userid";
 $result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query="Select threadid from notifications where notifor=$userid and threadid is NOT NULL";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($k>0)
  echo "data:($k)\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing `sleep(3)` from **onlineStudents.php**. That solved things.